# Datatable group by issue r.Field<T>

Tags: c#, linq

i was searching datatable group by option and found solution in stackoverflow.

```
DataTable t = //
var groups = t.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<T>("columnName"))
```

What does this mean... `r.Field<T>`. why `Field<T>`?
Can't I here specify `r.Field<Customer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/02/05/type-safety-linq-to-datasets-part-2.aspx

**Edited**:

> 1) why Field?

`Field<T>` method : DataTable is not typed one,the values to be saved as object. so the Field method returns the value of the column with generic type parameter, thus enable type checking.

If it is a typed DataTable then you can `Field<Customer.ID>`

  -